# How to convert JSON to map using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, converters

I have to convert a nested JSON to map using javascript.

JSON file

```
{
"centers" : {
  "ER" : {
    "admin":{
      "users" : {
        "emp1" : {
          "password" : "abcdefgh",
          "username" : "pankaj-roy"
        },
        "emp2" : {
          "password" : "12345678",
          "username" : "niketan-shah"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

I have to create a map from the above JSON file.

MAP

```
key          value
centers      ER
ER           admin
admin        users
users        emp1,emp2
emp1         password,username
emp2         password,username
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there a particular problem you are having with this? Do you know the keys in advance?

Comment: what is your desired object?

Comment: yeah..i know the keys in advance..and my desired object is to create a map like above.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```js
function keyMap(src, target){
  target = target || {};
  Object.keys(src).forEach(function(propName){
     var prop = src[propName];
     if(typeof prop == "object"){
       target[propName] = Object.keys(prop).join(',');
       keyMap(prop, target);
     }
  });
  return target;
};

var result = keyMap({
"centers" : {
  "ER" : {
    "admin":{
      "users" : {
        "emp1" : {
          "password" : "abcdefgh",
          "username" : "pankaj-roy"
        },
        "emp2" : {
          "password" : "12345678",
          "username" : "niketan-shah"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
});
                      
console.log(result);
```

Comment: FYI most browsers do support the `Object.keys` method, only MSIE8 and older doesn't.

Comment: You are right. I though it was an ES6 feature. In that case we do not need lodash.